# Understanding Kotlin access modifiers

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a child class in java, a parent class in kotlin and SuperParent class in Java, I have a issue in accessing field of Kotlin class, it shows error **Error:(11, 28) java: count has private access in Parent** Heres the code :

```
     public class Child extends Parent {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Child child = new Child();
                child.getParentCount();
            }

            private void getParentCount() {
    **//here error comes (Error:(11, 28) java: count has private access in Parent)**
                System.out.println(***count***);
            }
        }

        open class Parent : SuperParent() {
            protected var count: Int =0
            init {
    // but this works properly , if I remove the error in child class
                println(superCount)
            }

        }

        public class SuperParent {
            protected int superCount = 5;

            public SuperParent() {
// this also prints properly on removing error
                System.out.println(superCount);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: from Java, you should be able to use `getCount()` (and `setCount()`) in place of `count`.

Long answer:

This is a result of how Kotlin handles properties.

In Java, fields (member variables) may have any scope.  But in practice, making them public prevents you from controlling how they're accessed or modified, so the usual pattern is to keep them private and have accessor methods (`get()` and, if writable, `set()`).

Because that pattern is so common, and verbose, Kotlin takes care of it for you.  Kotlin properties *look* like fields, but (in Kotlin/JVM) they're implemented with private fields, and automatically-generated accessor methods with the relevant scope.  When you use the field, Kotlin automatically calls the relevant accessor.

If you're writing pure Kotlin, all that is hidden, and you don't need to worry about it.  But this question illustrates how it can cause surprises when you mix Java and Kotlin!

Luckily, the workaround is usually simple enough.  In this case, `Parent` defines the property `protected var count: Int = 0`.  The resulting bytecode will have a *private* field called `count`, and protected `getCount()` and `setCount()` methods.  So you can get the desired effect by calling those methods.  (This is what you'd commonly do in Java anyway, of course.)

There are a few corner cases where it's not so simple (e.g. if you're extending a class which already defines a method clashing with an accessor), but those are pretty rare.

Comment: so what is the importance of "protected" modifier in kotlin

Comment: `protected` means that it's accessible within the class and any subclasses.  See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html